# Facebook rest client in java

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-rest-api

I don't know why I download facebook-java-api-3.0.2. It doesen't have class FacebookRestClient... I find some example using FacebookRestClient but I can't use it.... can u help me?? Something has change.. but I dont know what FacebookRestClient has changed???
https://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-api/downloads/list?can=1&q=&colspec=Filename+Summary+Uploaded+ReleaseDate+Size+DownloadCount

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Facebook REST API has been officially deprecated**. You can now use the `Graph API` provided by Facebook for data retrival.

References :

- [Deprecating the REST API](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/616/)
- [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/)

Answer (score 0):

The latest upload was 2009, so it may be outdated.
You can try other sdks on [Facebook developers page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdks/). Or you may wanna have a look at [this java sdk](http://projects.spring.io/spring-social-facebook/) listed on the page.